# Why cant click on div tag?

Tags: jquery

Clicking on this div tag created a simple event to output a log window, but it doesn't work. How do I work?

```js
$('#b').on('click', function() {
  console.log("click");
});
```

```css
#b {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #444444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="b">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor<br>asd</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the order of the three parts (js, css, `<div>`)? The script part has to be located after the `<div id="b">` element.

Comment: demo works as expected add other details to recreate problem

Comment: You always have to apply events to an element after it has been created. Either you could say something like 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b").click(function(){
    ....
    })
});

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#b").click(function(){
      console.log("clicked");
   });
});
```